# What's the meaning of this sentence: "Für Ulrike war der Wintersport mit dem Gipsbein vorbei, der Urlaub zum Glück nicht"?

Tags: meaning

> Für Ulrike war der Wintersport mit dem Gipsbein vorbei, der Urlaub zum Glück nicht.

I think that Urlike's leg was in a cast by the time the winter sport was over, but fortunately the holiday wasn't over. Is that right? What's the meaning of that sentence?

Comment: The second part of the sentence is an abbreviation that refers to the first one. Compare to "Für Ulrike war der Wintersport mit dem Gipsbein vorbei" and "Für Ulrike war der Urlaub mit dem Gipsbein zum Glück nicht vorbei".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a weird phrasing for someone who is not a native speaker, indeed. It means the following:

> Getting/having her leg in a cast put an end to her doing winter sports, but fortunately not to her vacation.

The "mit" is used as a sort of "by, through, on account of" and the while part "mit dem Gipsbein" does refer to the whole clause (as opposed to the winter sport) and it answers to "why/when" without being a proper answer.